# Javascript: How to solve sending message from background to HTML script.js file?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

I am having some trouble with my small project. Currently I listen for firebase updates in my background.js file. And when an update is detected I send a message to my HTML script file to add a new html element to the popup. So far this works, just fine, with one exception.

How the DB works is when the user click on a tab, the URL is stored in the DB with a user typed message as its child. What i am then actually listeing for is if a new child has been added.
**Background.js file**

```
function checkLivechat() {
  try {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`livechat/${encodeUrlToBase64(lastUrl)}/messages`)
      .on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
        console.log("retrieve  messages now");
        try {
          var html = "";
          html += "<li>";
          html += snapshot.val().time + " ~ " + snapshot.val().message;
          html += "</li>";

          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "retrieveChat", data: html });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

HTML script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender) {
  if (request.message === "retrieveChat") {
    try {
      document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += request.data;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    // sendResponse({ farewell: "Hello, Background!" });
  }
});
```

Now the problem is, when i reload the extension (not the page) and navigate to a tab, which URL is already stored in the database, i get this annoying error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving
> end does not exist.

I think the problem is that the background file is executed before the HTML script, and when it tries to send a message to the HTML script it fails, because is hasn’t loaded yet.

Not sure if this is relatefd to this issue, but i also get this warning:

> Event handler of 'message' event must be added on the initial
> evaluation of worker script.

**Not sure if this is the actual reason. Any ideas on how to solve this?**

Comment: The sequence of actions you perform is somewhat unclear, but if the only nuisance is the error message you can simply suppress it by adding a parameter to sendMessage like this:  `()=>chrome.runtime.lastError`

Comment: Well I want to solve the issue not just suppress the error. Because when I get the error, it crashes and I can no longer “add” to the DB from the popup

Comment: Then maybe you can add more info: how the "tab is clicked", how this html script runs, how it's declared/loaded, what exactly "crashes" means, how the "popup" is declared/loaded and how it's related to this html. For example, if it's a browser_action or page_action it can't receive messages if it's not shown.

Comment: oh wow i actually solved the issue, it was really simple. I was just being silly for no reason